# Custom Table ADT (map) FSM (finite state machine)

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, data-structures

I have to code essentially what would mimic a std::map. I have a templated pair class, and a table class.

I am given a transition table:

```
        A       B       C       D       E
nke     fa1     ok1     fa1     fa1     fa1
ok1     ok2     fa2     fa2     fa2     fa2
ok2     ok3     fa3     fa3     fa3     fa3
ok3     nke     nke     nke     nke     nke
fa1     fa2     fa2     fa2     fa2     fa2
fa2     fa3     fa3     fa3     fa3     fa3
fa3     nke     nke     nke     nke     nke
```

and an action table:

```
          A             B           C            D          E
nke             
ok1     
ok2     
ok3     alarm       alarm       alarm       unlock      alarm
fa1     
fa2     
fa3     alarm       alarm       alarm       alarm       alarm
```

Basically, I'm suppose to code a security system, where a door opens after someone punches in the combination BAAD. Anything else will sound the alarm.

I understand the concept, but I do not understand how to create a mapping of the table.

Below in the header file,

```
int (*Mapping)( Key k);
```

I cannot figure out how I would map key to value using the action and transition table.

How do I map the values of the table by primary key and value?

Please ask if I need to supply anymore information,

Table Header File:

```
#ifndef  TABLE_H
#define  TABLE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include "pair.h"    // Pair class


using namespace std;
// implements a table containing key/value pairs.
// a table does not contain multiple copies of the same item.
// types T and Key must have a default constructor


template < class Key, typename T >
class Table
{
public:
Table();  //default constructor
~Table(); //destructor

typedef Key key_type;
// for  convenience

private:
// table implemented using a one dimensional array of key-value pairs
int tableSize;
Pair< key_type, T > *the_table;


int (*Mapping)( Key k);
// Mapping is a function which maps keys to
// an array index; ie a key to address mapping
// the idea is that Mapping will act on a given key
// in such a way as to return the relative postion
// in the sequence at which we expect to find the key
// Mapping will be used in the remove, add, lookup. =
// member functions and copy constructor

public:
// for debugging
void   print();

Table( int n, int (*map)( Key k)  );
// map is a function to map key to address
// in the implementation
// set the function ie have the code line
// Mapping = map;
// populates table with default values
// for the class Key and T

bool insert(  Pair<  Key, T >  kvpair );
// return true if item could be added to the
// table false if item was not added.

bool remove(  const Key  aKey );
// erase the key/value pair with the specified key
// from the table and return if successful
// removed item is replaced with default
// values for Key and T

T  lookUp (const Key aKey) ;
// what if key not in table??

//need copy constructor
//need destructor
// void operator= ( const Table & initTable );
// bool empty() const;
// is the table empty?
// bool full() const;
// is the table full?
// int size() const;
// return the number of elements in the table
// bool isIn(const Key& key) const;
// returns true/false in response to obvious question
};

#include "table.t"

#endif
```

Comment: You have 35 possible pairs. Are you asking for a hash function that will map each pair to a unique array index? Also what is the point of using templates? Is there any reason you don't just use two enums such as `namespace alarm{ enum state { nke, //...}; enum input { A, //...} }`?

Comment: Yes I am asking how to map each pair to a unique array index.  The point of using templates is for the code to be generic.

Comment: Let me try to reword that. When you use templates, the template arguments typically have some kind of purpose. What are `Key` and `T` supposed to represent? Is `Key` supposed to be a state (nk0, ...), a transition (A,B,...), an action (alarm, ...), or a pair/combination of those? You state in there can be "no duplicate items". Does that mean no duplicate keys like a normal map or no duplicate key-value pairs?

Comment: Key: (nke, B)  T: (ok1)  Key represents a pair, and T represents the value.